# Python scikit-learn sparse matrix clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, information-retrieval

Below is agglomerative clustering from scikit-learn. The problem is, to use the .fit method I need to convert the sparse matrix representation to an array. Since I have 80k documents with around 400k terms, the created array will have 80k x 400k elements. This will be a huge array and naturally, my computer has no memory and raised an Exception.

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = n_clusters,
                                    linkage = linkage,
                                    affinity = affinity,
                                    distance_threshold = distance_threshold)
model = model.fit(vectorspace.toarray())
```

With KMeans, I don't need to transform the sparse matrix representation to an array. Notice that I don't need to call the .toarray() inside the model.fit(). Therefore, my computer does not raise an Exception, since it does not use that much memory.

```
model=KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)

model = model.fit(vectorspace)
```

Does anyone know of any other python module or a workaround for this? I want to make Agglomerative Clustering exclusively with sparse matrixes, so I can do this with a large document collection, such as mine. Notice that my computer raises an Error and I can't even compute the clusters.